# edit multiple line at once in text editor

Tags: text

we can add four space at once to all the selected text line by pressing tab button. is there anyway that we can add or remove texts in front or back of each line at once.
actually I have a text file where every line ends with ":x". here x is random numbers
I want to remove all of them at once. any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notepad++ for that. Use Replace tool with enabled regular expressions and such search string: `x:[0-9].*$` (don't enable ". matches newline"). It will find occurences like `abcx:123` but ignore `abcx:` or `x:`